# Show value in a special position with MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a simple table, but want to add a code so i can put a special result in a chosen position.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I also have a column called position. If this has 4 as value i want it to show as the 4th result, if value is 7 as the 7th row and so on. Else I want it to order by rating.

Is this possible? With CASE maybe?

I tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN position = 4 THEN 4
    WHEN position = 9 THEN 9 
    ELSE 0 END,
    rating DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This just hides those with values 4 and 9 in position.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

should give the following table

| Name | Rating | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike Brown | 93 | 0 |
| John Doe | 85 | 0 |
| Alex Johnson | 78 | 0 |
| Jane Smith | 72 | 0 |
| Emily White | 60 | 0 |
| Sarah Lee | 52 | 4 |
| Robert Miller | 49 | 0 |
| Emma Davis | 39 | 9 |
| David Clark | 38 | 0 |
| Olivia Hall | 30 | 0 |

I rather want a code to show following table

| Name | Rating | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike Brown | 93 | 0 |
| John Doe | 85 | 0 |
| Alex Johnson | 78 | 0 |
| Sarah Lee | 52 | 4 |
| Jane Smith | 72 | 0 |
| Emily White | 60 | 0 |
| Robert Miller | 49 | 0 |
| David Clark | 38 | 0 |
| Emma Davis | 39 | 9 |
| Olivia Hall | 30 | 0 |

Comment: While debugging, move the case to the SELECT list for a while, and you'll understand more.

Comment: can't quite get my head round this, where would a position of 9 with a rating of 4 appear? sample data an expected outcome would help

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve

Answer (score 0):

I can get *close* (it's not perfect) by first setting a row-number based on the rating

```
SELECT *
   , row_number() over (order by rating) rn
FROM table
```

Then I can use both that and the row number at the same level to determine the order:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
       , row_number() over (order by rating) rn
    FROM table
) t
ORDER BY coalesce(nullif(position, 0), rn), position desc
```

The problem is it will lose a spot every time we do have a `position` match. Getting around this requires knowing how many rows have a set `position` value, so we can leave a place for them.

Answer (score 0):

I have this split into three steps...

---

***1. filter the data down to 10 rows (adjustable by changing the two 10's to `n`)***

If you want 10 rows, you want all rows where the position override is 10 or less, with the remaining rows based on their rating (highest first)

```
WITH
  filtered AS
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    example
  WHERE
    position <= 10
  ORDER BY
    position DESC,
    rating   DESC
  LIMIT
    10
),
```

---

***2. rank the data in two batches (normal, and "fixed position")***

The "normal" data (`position = 0`) just get ranked normally, based on `rating`, from `1` to `n`, in ***descending*** order.

- in the sample data's case from `1` to `8`
- as there are 8 "normal" rows

The "fixed position" data (`position <> 0`) gets ranked on the `position` but in ***ascending*** order.

- `Sarah Lee`  with `position = 4` gets ranked `1`
- `Emma Davis` with `position = 9` gets ranked `2`

```
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY IF(position = 0, 0,       1       )
          ORDER BY IF(position = 0, rating, -position) DESC
    )
      AS initial_rank
  FROM
    filtered
)
```

---

***3. sort the data to the final positions***

The final step is to sort based on the combination of the `initial_rank` from above, but adjusted for the existence of "fixed position" rows.

First, we put all the fixed position rows in the same position as the row we want them to ***follow***.

For `Sarah Lee` it's simple

- she has `position = 4`
- we want to put ***after*** the ***third*** highest rating
- so, we'll put her interim position at `3` (Same as Alex)

For `Emma Davis` we need to adjust that slightly

- she has `position = 9`
- but we already have two people at position `3` (`Alex Jackson` & `Sarah Lee`)
- which means that we want to put `Emma` ***after*** the ***seventh*** highest rating
- that will put her after 7 "normal" rows ***and*** Sarah
- which would be 9th overall
- so, we'll put her interim position at `7` (Same as David)

"Conveniently" this means that the position we want to put each "fixed position" row ***after*** is simple...

- `interim_position` = `position - initial_rank`
- `Sarah Lee`  = `4 - 1` = `3`
- `Emma Davis` = `9 - 2` = `7`

Then, to account for all "interim positions" that have more than one row, we also sort by the `position` column

- "normal" rows have `0`, so they always go first
- "fixed position" rows have ascending values, so they go next

```
SELECT
  name, rating,
  IF(position = 0, initial_rank, position - initial_rank)  AS position_interim,
  position                                                 AS position_tiebreak
FROM
  sorted
ORDER BY
  IF(position = 0, initial_rank, position - initial_rank),
  position
```

| name | rating | position_interim | position_tiebreak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike Brown | 93 | 1 | 0 |
| John Doe | 85 | 2 | 0 |
| Alex Johnson | 78 | 3 | 0 |
| ***Sarah Lee*** | ***52*** | ***3*** | ***4*** |
| Jane Smith | 72 | 4 | 0 |
| Emily White | 60 | 5 | 0 |
| Robert Miller | 49 | 6 | 0 |
| David Clark | 38 | 7 | 0 |
| ***Emma Davis*** | ***39*** | ***7*** | ***9*** |
| Olivia Hall | 30 | 8 | 0 |

---

***DEMO ON dbfiddle.uk*** : https://dbfiddle.uk/7g2sgApt

*(Includes a shorter version, but it will be slower on large datasets due to `LIMIT`ing last rather than first.)*

---